# Download FX historical data (5 years) using R?

Tags: r, quantmod, quandl, forex

Is it possible to download hourly data from Quandl (or another provider) using something like:

library(Quandl) 
Quandl('EUR/USD',type=hourly) ?

and if so more than 3 or 5 years?